# Bluebird Promise resolve with sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, bluebird, resolve

I'm trying to resolve an empty array :

```
function getAncestors(parentId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (!!parentId) {
            Category.findOne(parentId).then(function(parent) {
                parent.ancestors.push(parentId);
                resolve(parent.ancestors);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });
        } else {
            resolve([]);
        }
    });
};
```

and it works but my sails console ends up logging undefined when resolve([]) happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should show where and how you do the logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to rewrite to this:

```
function getAncestors(parentId) {
    if (!!parentId) {
        return Category.findOne(parentId).then(function(parent) {
            parent.ancestors.push(parentId);
            return parent.ancestors;
        });
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve([]);
    }
};
```